# How to use a returned ArrayList in another method

Tags: java, arraylist, methods

I think I am getting myself confused...I am calling a method (method B) which generates an array list. The calling is done from inside another method (method A). I am then trying to use the returned arrayList in method A but it seems to be empty. The arrayList generated in method B is not empty however so I think I've got some return ArrayList issue that I don't understand. Here is my code:

```
public void ExtractNew(String doc,String day) {

    ExtractTotal(docSlim,day);
}

public ArrayList<List<String>> ExtractTotal(String docSlim,String day) {
    ////Code for multidimensional arrayList creation omitted
            Arr2d.add(Arr);
            }
    }
    return Total;
}
```

Comment: That got a -1 in 25 seconds. It can't be that bad?

Comment: So... where is Total defined + you don't fill it anywhere in ExtractTotal.. maybe you should return Arr2d?

Comment: Ignore those people. You are not assigning a reference to the returned list. You should do something like this List<List<String>> totalList = ExtractTotal(docSlim,day);

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value

Comment: A possible reason you immediately go the downvote might be because you are not camelCasing your variables. You are Capitalizing it, which to most of us would mean that is a class and not an object. It just makes your code difficult to read.

Comment: What is your variable `Total`? I don't see it defined anywhere.

Comment: Style note: you should use constant naming conventions for variables and methods. It will make youre code easier to read. You can see java convetions http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html

Comment: Aha. Criticism noted. Thanks. Forever on the improvement

Comment: @SebastianZeki maybe post a small code sample representing your problem rather than your large code block.

Comment: Done. Thanks @John Doe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not adding to the `Total` ArrayList inside the `ExtractTotal` method.

Try this before returning it:

```
Total = Arr2d;
```

Assuming that `Total` is a class level variable here of course....

Comment: Aha. That's the answer.